# Android created Zip does not hold contained file sizes

Tags: android, zip

I have put in place the ability to archive user data for my application by creating a compressed file.

I create the compressed file like this :

```
try
{
    int iBufferSize = 2048;
    int iByteCount = 0;
    byte btData[] = new byte[iBufferSize];
    File fZipFile = new File(ARCHIVE_FILE);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fZipFile);
    ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);

    BufferedInputStream bis = null;
    FileInputStream fIn = null;
    ZipEntry ze = null;
    File[] fPartitions = new File(FILES_PATH).listFiles();
    for(File fPartition : fPartitions)
    {
        lFileSize = fPartition.length();
        fIn = new FileInputStream(fPartition);
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(fIn, iBufferSize);
        ze = new ZipEntry(fPartition.getName());
        ze.setSize(lFileSize);
        zos.putNextEntry(ze);
        while((iByteCount = bis.read(btData, 0, iBufferSize)) != -1)
        {
            zos.write(btData, 0, iByteCount);
        }
        bis.close();
        zos.closeEntry();
    }
    zos.close();

    bis.close();
    fIn.close();
    bOk = true;
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now, when I try to restore the contents, I am not able to get the original file size. Here is how I am doing the expansion :

```
try
{
    // open the archive
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fArchive);
    ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(fis));
    bBuffer = new byte[2048];

    // iterate through all files, putting them back into the same place
    ze = zis.getNextEntry();
    while(ze != null)
    {
        strFileName = ze.getName();
        strFileName = FILE_PATH + "/" + strFileName;
        fCheck = new File(strFileName);
        lZipFileSize = ze.getSize(); // <--- returns -1 systematically
        lTargetFileSize = fCheck.length();
        fCheck = null;
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(strFileName);

        // read the data
        while((iCount = zis.read(bBuffer)) != -1)
        {
            fos.write(bBuffer, 0, iCount);
        }
        fos.close();

        ze = zis.getNextEntry();
    }
    zis.close();
    fis.close();
    bOk = true;
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have noted that `ze.getSize()` is returning -1 systematically.

How can I store and get the individual file sizes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so if you come across this problem, here is how I worked around it.

Use the ZipFile class for reading the zip file.
Inspired from [ZipInputStream: getting file size of -1 when reading](http://www.coderanch.com/t/563455/java/java/ZipInputStream-file-size-reading) and [The ZipFileTest.java Android example source code](http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/android/tests/CoreTests/android/core/ZipFileTest.java.shtml)